# Visual Studio doesn't clean obj folders properly

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I am using VS 2022 (v17.0.2). I have two projects:

- Project A (depends on Project B)
- Project B (Class Library with a Nuget ref to `MongoDb.Bson`)

I have two git branches where Project B is a different implementation of dotnet.

> on git branch `/framwrk`:
>
> - Project A (.NET Framework 4.7)
> - Project B **(.NET Framework 4.7)**
>
> on git branch `/stndrd`:
>
> - Project A (.NET Framework 4.7)
> - Project B **(netstandard2.0)**

When I switch from branch `/stndrd` to `/framwrk`, the first build for Project B fails because of the following error:

`Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" framework.  Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore. (Project B)`

Clean and Rebuild doesn't fix the problem.
Right clicking on the solution and selecting "Restore NuGet Packages" doesn't fix it either, it says "All packages are already initialized and there is nothing to restore".

The only thing that seems to fix it is to manually delete the `\obj\project.assets.json` file inside Project B's project folder, then build.

My Question Is:
**Is there something else I could be doing to make it easier to swap back-and-forth between branches and re-build?**

Comment: The Tweaks-Extensions contains an option to fully clean bin and obj folders on Clean, is that an option? https://github.com/madskristensen/Tweakster#deleteoutputartifacts

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't use extensions in the enterprise I am at.  Instead I wrote a short console app to blow /obj/ away.  I was wondering if this was something I was doing wrong that was causing this.

Comment: Probably not, this is a fairly common problem when switching between different framework or project versions. Cleaning obj as a pre-build event probably makes it a bit more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

When I've encountered that issue, doing a restore on the command line resolves it (such as `msbuild My.sln /t:restore` which just does the restore or `msbuild /r My.sln` which does the restore and a build).  I'm not sure why VS doesn't do anything when you tell it to Restore, it may have something cached that should be invalidated (I'd suggest opening a feedback item if you can provide a sample repo that can reproduce the issue reliably).

You could try leveraging the `post-checkout` git hook to run the command line restore whenever a branch switch occurs.  From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout):

> The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have changed), and **a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch checkout (changing branches, flag=1)** or a file checkout (retrieving a file from the index, flag=0).

A pre-build event to clear the obj directory would also work, but it would be detrimental to incremental builds when you're not changing branches.

Comment: Okay thanks, I am still dealing with this issue on a daily basis, I will check out your solution as soon as I get a chance.